# Extension field of $x^3 - 2$ in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I know this has been asked previous on Stackexchange, but I just want to have something clarified:

I am supposed to find an extension K of Q having all roots of $x^3 - 2$ such that $[K:\mathbb Q] = 6.$

Setting $\alpha = 2^\frac{1}{3}$ and $\omega = e^\frac{2\pi i}{3}$, I can write all the roots in a basis such that the degree is $3$: $$\{\alpha,\alpha \omega, \alpha \omega^2\}$$ I guess this is a field of degree 3? So I am then supposed to add three more random linear independent elements such that $[K:\mathbb Q] = 6$?

Comment: No: $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ has degree $3$, since $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$. Note $\omega$ does *not* belong to this field, nor $\alpha\omega(^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = [K:\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$. Now you took a third root of unit $\xi$, and $p(x) = x^2 + x +  1 $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ which has $\xi$ as root.

From this what is the degree $[\mathbb Q (\xi): \mathbb Q]$? What does this tell you about $[K:\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}]$?

What you conclude from that?

Comment: Right, I think I finally got the essence ofit. So we have hat $[\mathbb Q(\zeta) : \mathbb Q]$ is isomorphic to the field $a + b\zeta + c\zeta^2$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is of 3. Here $\mathbb {Q}(\zeta) = \zeta^2 + \zeta + 1$, which is irreducible. And taking K mod this irreducible polynomial, this is isomorphic to a field of degree 2. Hence $[\mathbb{Q} : K] = 6$.

Comment: Exactly! That's the idea. Careful, the notation is $[K:\mathbb Q]$.

Comment: Of course, Yeah. Thank you very much, it contributed a lot to the understanding! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Keep up with the good work.

Comment: I didn't understand how $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is a part of the extension field... To my understanding you are using $\alpha$ and $\zeta$ as the same when writing $[K : \mathbb Q(\alpha)]$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta) : \mathbb Q]$... So the problem here is that I know that i generate a field of degree 6, but Im not convinced that it contains the roots.

Comment: Here $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\xi$ is a third root of unit. What you have found so far is that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] = 3$ and $[\mathbb Q (\xi) : \mathbb] = 2$. Now you need to show that $x^2 + x + 1$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, in order to conclude that $[\mathbb K :\mathbb Q (\alpha)] = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The field extension is generated by $\alpha_1=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\alpha_2=i\sqrt{3}$

Now use that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=deg(f_{\alpha})$ where $f_{\alpha}\in \mathbb Q[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and the formula $[M:K]=[M:L]\cdot [L:K]$ for field extensions $K\subset L\subset M$

Comment: I'd say $\alpha_2=\mathrm e^{\frac{2\mathrm i \pi}3}$.

Comment: The roots can be written as $x_1=\sqrt[3]{2},x_2=\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}),x_3=\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: You don't have any $\sqrt 2$ in your formulae.

Comment: Sry, there was indeed a typo. Fixed $\alpha_2$:)